# Logging module outputs nothing

Tags: python, logging, pyscripter

I'm using Automate the boring stuff and this code is from the book:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.debug('Start of program')

def factorial(n):
    logging.debug('Start of factorial(%s)' % (n))
    total = 1
    for i in range(n + 1):
        total *= i
        logging.debug('i is ' + str(i) + ', total is ' + str(total))
    logging.debug('End of factorial(%s)' % (n))
    return total

print(factorial(5))
logging.debug('End of program')
```

But in my system the logging.debug statements print nothing, and when I enclose them with print() statements they print None. I'm using Python 3.6.3 64bit version.

Edit: I typed this code in the python shell and it worked fine, so I'm narrowing this problem to the PyScripter IDE. Any ideas?

Edit #2: Found the solution: For pyscripter users go to Run>Python Engine>select Internal or use alt+f9 for external run.

Comment: Works for me; I see debug output.  The program produces the incorrect output, but debug output is generated.

Comment: Really strange. Yeah I know the factorial returns 0, but something is definitely wrong with python, or it could be the fact that I'm using the PyScripter IDE.

Comment: Add your EDIT #2 as an answer, and accept it.  The question is not the place to add answers; that leaves the question unanswered and anyone who encounters the problem won't know this question has found a solution.